# Removing one file from a Pull request in github

Tags: github

Accidentally, I have committed one specific (additional) file in my Pull Request which shouldn't be there. I tried `git fetch` and then `git checkout -- file` but its giving me a patherror. So I switched to master and created a new branch with `git checkout -b newbranch` but still its showing me the same. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is:

- checkout your PR branch (that you already have pushed)
- delete (git rm) the extra file
- push

That will update the existing PR, and the file will no longer be visible.